# I am new to shiny and i try to build an application.i got an error

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

```
error
sqlQuery(con,"insert into samp values('",input$text1,"',",input$text2,")");
Error in sqlQuery(con, "insert into samp values('", input$text1, "',",  :
  object 'input' not found
ui.R
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(mainPanel(textInput("text1"," ",value = " "),
 numericInput("text2"," ",value = " "), actionButton("b1", label = "select"),
 tableOutput("txt1"))))
server.R
shinyServer(function(input,output){output$txt1<-renderTable({input$b1
if(input$b1==0 )return()isolate({con<-odbcConnect("sample",uid="amma",pwd ="amma")sqlTables(con)sqlQuery(con,"insertintosampvalues('",input$text1,"',",input$text2,")");sqlQuery(con,"select * from samp"); })})})
```

how to write the insert query by receving values from an interface?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I added your code to [a gist](https://gist.github.com/corynissen/d52bdca7b7a8a1a8512a) so it's more readable and runnable via shiny.

It can be run via:

```
shiny::runGist("https://gist.github.com/corynissen/d52bdca7b7a8a1a8512a")
```

I added a library(RODBC) call at the top and paste0 around the strings you were trying to concatenate. See if that helps... I can't really test it without the db.